# Find max sum of two non-intersecting sub arrays

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of integers, take any two non-intersecting subarrays, A1 and A2. A subarray could be empty too. we have to return the max(sum(A1,A2)). The return value is the maximum possible sum of two subarrays of the given array.

**My Thoughts:**
Find the max sum subarray. This will give two new subarrays, the left of it and the right of it. Find the max sum subarray left and right and choose the optimal one. I am not sure if this will yield the max answer.

Any ideas or approach?

Comment: The approach I mentioned doesn't work. A=[-9,-5,-9,-8,9,7,-10,10,9] max sub array sum is for index [4,8] = 9+7-10+10+9 = 18 + 7 = 25. The max subarray of left split = 5 so the algorithm will yield 30 as the answer. Whereas the correct answer is 35 for indices [4,5] and [7,8]

Answer (score 2):

Find the [max subarray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane%27s_algorithm) ending at index `i` going left and find the max subarray ending at index `i` going right. Then for each candidate, update the best result with the larger of the current best or `max_subarray_sum_on_the_left[i] + max_subarray_sum_on_the_right[i+1]`.

In case it was unclear -- when performing Kadane's algorithm for each direction, save for each index the best seen from that direction. This leads to an `O(n)` overall solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create array `left[]` such that `left[i] = max subarray sum ending at index i` (takes `O(N)` time)
2. Create array `right[]` such that `right[i] = max subarray sum starting at index i` (takes `O(N)` time)
3. Iterate over the arrays and keep track of the max value visited such that `left[i] = max possible sum over all subarrays ending at i` and `right[i] = max possible sum over all subarrays starting at i`. (takes `O(N)` time)
4. Loop `i` from `1` to `N-1`, where `i` is the index about which we'll "partition" our array and choose non-intersecting subarrays. For a given `i`, the answer will be `left[i] + right[i]`

The solution has `O(N)` space and time complexity.

Comment: Could you please help me understand why a heap is needed and the solution needs to be O(n log n)? I thought the solution I proposed has O(n) time complexity. (I added further clarification to my answer to explain that.)

Comment: @גלעדברקן I overlooked the iterative solution, so used a heap straight away. You're right, I've corrected the answer